# correct verse and its reference - govinda prekṣaṇā kṣepi vāspa pūrā vivarṣinam ucce anindadānanda maravinda vilocanā

Tags: puranas, krishna, mantras, reference-request, gaudiya-vaishnavism

I think I might have incorrectly listened to this verse from a lecture and wanted to know what's the correct verse for it:

> govinda prekṣaṇā kṣepi vāspa pūrā vivarṣinam
> ucce anindadānanda maravinda vilocanā

> गोविंद प्रेक्षणा क्षेपि वास्प पूरा विवर्षिनम उच्चे अनिन्ददानन्द मरविन्द विलोचना

based on the wording it sounds like its from the book [Shri Ujjaval Nilamani](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/shri-ujjaval-nilamani-rare-book-nzc283/)

Does anyone know the correct verse for it.